# How to make Nginx server available on public IP

Tags: nginx, web-hosting

I am trying to run a small website from my home WiFi, so I set up a reverse Nginx proxy from localhost:8000 to port 93.

I am wondering how this server can be accessible from my public ip address instead of just my localhost at port 93.

Currently, I have the server_name in the sever config set to a name which maps to my public ip address in `/etc/hosts`. Is port forwarding required to make the sever accessible from my public IP address? If so, how can I set that up.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you for your help.

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, this should be really simple, all you would need to do is to open port 93 from your ubuntu machine in your router to be accessible for http or https traffic from the outside and you should be good to go.

Comment: Check if that port is currently in use by something else, or if closed then yes you would need to forward router port 93 to your ubuntu 93, and how that is done depends on your router brand.